# Access to JBoss4 log4j file While JBoss Is Running

Tags: jboss, log4j

I am running JBoss 4.0.5.GA and--I assume--it's included log4j package, both on OS X Mountain Lion. I have configured `../server/site/conf/log4j.xml` to capture startup/shutdown messages in a separate file:

```
<appender name="SERVER_EVENTS" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
    <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server_events.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="false"/>
    <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
     </layout>
</appender>

<category name="org.jboss.system.server.Server">
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="SERVER_EVENTS"/>
</category>
```

This works as far as capturing the startup/shutdown lines. I am using a LaunchAgent to watch that `server_events.log` file for changes. I have verified that the LaunchAgent loads, and is functional.

The LaunchAgent responds at the following times:

- When `run.sh` kicks off and the `server_events.log` file is truncated.
- On server shutdown, when a group of log entries ends with "Shutdown complete."

The problem I'm having is capturing the "Started in ..." message. After much Googling, I have an idea what the problem is, and I am unsure if a solution even exists. I believe the message is not getting captured because JBoss has "a hold" on the file while it's running. You can see above where I am explicitly requesting that JBoss "ImmediateFlush" the messages. I was under the impression that that is the default, but I can see in Finder that the file is 0 bytes, but watching the file opened in Sublime Text 2 reveals the startup message.

Is there any way to ensure that the startup message be written to disk immediately after it gets sent? Or am I out of luck since I'm running such an old version of JBoss?

Comment: immediateflush is certainly not the default and often not recommended. is there a reason you'd need it?

Comment: If the messages I'm capturing need to exist in the file, then the change needs to be written to disk in the log file immediately so I can grep the log file.